# mixing flex 4 gui components with papervision3d

Tags: user-interface, papervision3d, flex4

I'd like to mix papervision rendering (either "fullscreen" or constrained in some area) with flex gui components laying over that rendering.. how could this be achieved?

For now I can design .mxml templates at hand and do some papervision rendering in a separate .as file (definig [SWF ...]), but I'm still very new at as3/flex, so don't assume anything, a detailed explanation will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance =)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you render with papervision3d ends up in a View(basic,bitmap, etc.), which extends Sprite, so it's a DisplayObject.

If you want to add a component over the rendering, just add that component as a sibling of the View in the display list.

You might find [Efflex](http://www.efflex.org/EfflexExplorer.html) interesting.